# How many counts the square number?

Tags: algorithms, education

For example I have a number is $55$. Can I check this for how many counts number's square create this number.

For example I have $55$ So, I know this number total from 5 number, which are

$$55 = 1^2+ 2^2+ 3^2+ 4^2 + 5^2$$ (In total $5$ sqaure numbers)

I found the counts is $5$ for $55$ . How can I found counts any number. Is there any formula or equation? I dont want to know which number's square. I just want to know how many numbers squares create this number. In my example my answer is $5$. but If I can calculate this $10$ digit any number its too complex.

For example if my number was $652369$. How can I found how many numbers square total from? I just want to find how many number. I m sorry my english. I m using Delphi programming language.

Note: The numbers are not "consecutive" everytime.

Comment: You mean the maximal number? Since $25 = 5^2 = 3^2+4^2$. Also we can just add $1^2$ all day long. So the numbers should be distinct?

Comment: yes max counts of number. counts is 2 (3 and 4) in your example, but I want to find for every number in short time.

Comment: You might find this useful http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf - essentially the answer for big enough numbers is that its pretty close to the maximum number of distinct squares - that is, total up consecutive squares until you get to your target number, step back one or two, and adjust the squares in use to get your number.

Comment: I m checking it.thank you

Comment: I have in mind an algorithm that I think should work.

Take any number $n$ for example $n=55$

Now take the square root of that number , if it's an integer then you are done. Else, subtract that number by 1.  and take the square root of $n-1$ and see if it's an integer and so on.

It would be a recursive algorithm. Maybe not the most efficient but it should work :)

Comment: 4 is always enough if they are not meant to be distinct. "sum of four squares", as a result of gaussian prime factorization.